# Can an email reach to the mail server other than its own recipient address's domain?

Tags: email, dns, smtp, google-apps

My company uses Google Apps service that works with our own domain.

I wonder how Google mail server can receive emails to my_account@my_company?

Can an email reach to the mail server - in this case Google server - which differs from recipient address's domain - my_company?

As I know, my company even has our own server and public IP address which is registered on DNS.

Comment: Hm.. Why is this question marked as 'put on as off topic' I don't think it's about google apps service, but about SMTP and DNS protocol. Thank Lorenzo Marcon, I didn't know what the MX record is at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're missing some points on how the whole email system works.
In very basic terms, when someone sends an email to your_account@your_company.com, a DNS request is made to find out the mailserver responsible for your_company.com email handling. You can check this by yourself by querying your DNS for the MX records asigned to your domain.

So, if your company is using Google Apps to handle the company accounts, your_domain.com must have google mail servers on the MX records for everything to work properly.

This is "how the email can reach my company servers" part. Around that, there's a whole bunch of other configurations that make the thing work.

Answer (score 0):

It goes to Google server first and then is just forwarded to your domain.

Comment: try to give answer with detail explanation